# I can't see whats wrong with my smarty code

Tags: php, smarty

```
{foreach from=$yesterday.data item='mkt' name='yloop'}    
<li style="margin: {if $smarty.foreach.yloop.index mod 2 == 0}0 !important{else}0 8px 0 0{/if};padding: 5px 0;list-style: none;border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;display: block;overflow: hidden;float: left;font-size: 11px;width: calc(50% - 4px);">
{if empty($mkt->market)}
<span class="flag {$mkt->market}" style="float: left;margin/left>20px ;display: block;width: 20px;height: 13px;margin: 0 4px 0 0;background-size: contain;border-radius: 2px;">XX</span>
{else}
<span class="flag {$mkt->market}" style="float: left;display: block;width: 20px;height: 13px;margin: 0 4px 0 0;background-size: contain;border-radius: 2px;background: url(https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.youniversalmedia.com/ym-signature/flags/{$mkt->market}.jpg) no-repeat     center center;"></span>
{/if}
<span class="nation" style="width: calc(58% - 21px);text-align: left;color: #777;float: left;">{$mkt->market|upper}</span>
<span class="money" style="width: calc(58% - 21px);text-align: right;color: #777;float: left;">{$mkt->revenue_EUR|round:2}€</span>
</li>
{/foreach}
```

The problem is the line `{if $smarty.foreach.yloop.index mod 2 == 0}0 !important{else}0 8px 0 0{/if}`

It doesn't display anything, if I change the condition in the if statement to always be true it works perfectly and I tried using % instead of mod but that didn't work.

I'm hoping there's some obvious mistake I'm making and any help would be great.

Comment: Show where your `foreach` starts.

Comment: My bad should have included all the code

Comment: Try to remove `'` from `name` property. Besides all looks good.